# HTML5 Video in Chome, SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, cross-domain

I am trying to have my webpage display a video from my video server. The video server is running on the same host as my webserver, but on a different port.

When I use `canvas.toDataURL()` to scrape the pixels off the video that is playing on the canvas, I am getting a "`Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18`" on the browser.
I am using Chrome, version 24.

Here is the HTTP header sent with the video page

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: video/x-mp4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2013 23:28:00 GMT
Server: OizysLight
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" allow cross origin resource sharing?

Comment: I am trying to capture a frame when the user hits a button. I am using canvas.toDataURL() to scrap the pixels off the video that is playing on the canvas.

Comment: I edited your question with that new information, since it might help someone in the future with the same problem. If you want to change anything about my edit, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the [`crossOrigin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) on the `<video>` element. You can set it to `anonymous` if the request for the video resource doesn't need cookies or HTTP auth, or `use-credentials` otherwise.

Mozilla has a writeup about [cross-domain images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image) on a `<canvas>`, and virtually all of it also applies to videos.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I needed to set the crossOrigin property on my video.

`video.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";`